# Regular Expression Anchors: VBScript.RegExp

Tags: regex, vbscript

What is the difference between

$ (End of Line)

and

\Z (End of String)

with VBScript.RegExp?

Is it simply that a String can have embedded CR + LF and $ sets the scope to what precedes CR + LF?

Or does it not matter when using VBScript.RegExp since this object does not accept files as input?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes a difference depending on your flags. If  Multiline is active (`/m`), `$` matches the end of every line (newlines), but `\Z` only matches  the last position on the string.

A string may contain multiple lines regardless of whether or not if came from a file, for example:
`"hello world\nfirefox 4 is out"`

See also: [Permanent Start of String and End of String Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#az)

Comment: Thanks - both for the answer (I finally got a handle on Multiline) & the link.